# Server error 500 for Java Spring tutorial sample

Tags: spring

I tried to follow this tutorial for Java Spring https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn1
In short, one is to design a controller that takes care of 4 different HTTP endpoints, that are build around a video uploading service.
My solution is the following controller:

```
/*
 * 
 * Copyright 2014 Jules White
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * 
 */
package org.magnum.dataup;

import org.magnum.dataup.model.Video;
import org.magnum.dataup.model.VideoStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import retrofit.http.Multipart;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.PUT;
import retrofit.http.Part;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@Controller
public class Controller01 {

    private Map<Long,Video> videos= new HashMap<>();
    private static final AtomicLong counter= new AtomicLong(0);


    private Map<Long,String> id2url= new HashMap<>();
        public Video save(Video entity) {
        checkAndSetId(entity);
        videos.put(entity.getId(), entity);
        return entity;
    }

    private void checkAndSetId(Video entity) {
        if ( entity.getId() == 0 ) {
            entity.setId(counter.incrementAndGet());
        }
    }

    private String getDataUrl(long videoId){
       String url = getUrlBaseForLocalServer() + "/video/" + videoId + "/data";
       return url;
    }

    private String getUrlBaseForLocalServer() {
           HttpServletRequest request =
               ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
           String base =
              "http://"+request.getServerName()
              + ((request.getServerPort() != 80) ? ":"+request.getServerPort() : "");
           return base;
    }

    /**
     * You will need to create one or more Spring controllers to fulfill the
     * requirements of the assignment. If you use this file, please rename it
     * to something other than "AnEmptyController"
     * 
     * 
         ________  ________  ________  ________          ___       ___  ___  ________  ___  __       
        |\   ____\|\   __  \|\   __  \|\   ___ \        |\  \     |\  \|\  \|\   ____\|\  \|\  \     
        \ \  \___|\ \  \|\  \ \  \|\  \ \  \_|\ \       \ \  \    \ \  \\\  \ \  \___|\ \  \/  /|_   
         \ \  \  __\ \  \\\  \ \  \\\  \ \  \ \\ \       \ \  \    \ \  \\\  \ \  \    \ \   ___  \  
          \ \  \|\  \ \  \\\  \ \  \\\  \ \  \_\\ \       \ \  \____\ \  \\\  \ \  \____\ \  \\ \  \ 
           \ \_______\ \_______\ \_______\ \_______\       \ \_______\ \_______\ \_______\ \__\\ \__\
            \|_______|\|_______|\|_______|\|_______|        \|_______|\|_______|\|_______|\|__| \|__|
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * 
     */
    public static final String DATA_PARAMETER = "data";
    public static final String ID_PARAMETER = "id";
    public static final String VIDEO_SVC_PATH = "/video";
    public static final String VIDEO_DATA_PATH = VIDEO_SVC_PATH + "/{id}/data";

    private VideoFileManager videoDataMgr;

    // You would need some Controller method to call this...
    public void saveSomeVideo(Video v, MultipartFile videoData) throws IOException {
         videoDataMgr.saveVideoData(v, videoData.getInputStream());
    }

    public void serveSomeVideo( Video v, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
         // Of course, you would need to send some headers, etc. to the
         // client too!
         //  ...
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        videoDataMgr.copyVideoData(v, response.getOutputStream());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/video", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Collection<Video> getVideoList() {
        List<Video> list= new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Map.Entry<Long,Video> entry: videos.entrySet() )
            list.add(entry.getValue());
        return list;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/video", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Video>
    addVideo( @RequestBody Video v ) {

        Video entry= Video.create()
            .withContentType("video/mp4")
            .withDuration(v.getDuration())
            .withSubject(v.getSubject())
            .withTitle(v.getTitle()).build();

        /**
         * what comes
         */
        entry.setLocation(v.getLocation());

        /**
         * what we generate
         */
        String url;
        checkAndSetId(entry);
        entry.setDataUrl(url= getDataUrl(counter.get()));
        videos.put(entry.getId(),entry);
        ResponseEntity<Video> entity= new ResponseEntity<>(entry,HttpStatus.OK);

        return entity;

    }

    @Multipart
    @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_DATA_PATH, method= {RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.POST}, consumes="multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    public
    VideoStatus
    setVideoData( @PathVariable(ID_PARAMETER) long id,
                  @RequestParam(DATA_PARAMETER) MultipartFile videoData,
                  HttpServletResponse response,
                  HttpServletRequest request
                  ) throws IOException {
        if ( !videos.containsKey(id) ) {
            response.sendError(404);
            return null;
            //return new ResponseEntity<VideoStatus>(new VideoStatus(VideoStatus.VideoState.READY),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        try {
            saveSomeVideo(videos.get(id),videoData);
            response.setStatus(200);
            return new VideoStatus(VideoStatus.VideoState.READY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.sendError(404);
            //return new ResponseEntity<VideoStatus>(new VideoStatus(VideoStatus.VideoState.READY),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Video> getData(
            @PathVariable("id") long id,
            HttpServletResponse request
            ) throws IOException {
        if ( !videos.containsKey(id) || !videoDataMgr.hasVideoData(videos.get(id)) ) {
            ResponseEntity<Video> entity= new ResponseEntity<Video>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            return entity;
        }
        ResponseEntity<Video> entity= new ResponseEntity<Video>(HttpStatus.OK);
        serveSomeVideo(videos.get(id),request);
        request.setContentType("video/mp4");
        return entity;
    }
}
```

However, when I run `AutoGraderTest`, it keeps reporting [image]

That is, somehow my `setVideoData` method contains stuff causing problems.
Most probably it is this `TypedFile` thing. I just wonder how to fix this problem? To run the above GitHub code one just needs to clone it
and paste the given `Controller01` inside the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `VideoFileManager` instance like this

```
videoData = VideoFileManager.get();
```